# Uwp Screen capture _framePool.FrameArrived not fired for Outlook

Tags: uwp

I am trying to capture application screen shot, I made a test with [Screen capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture).

For this document, it works for webbrowser application like Edge, but, if I choose to capture the Outlook Application, it will fail with `System.NullReferenceException`.

The full test code is in [Putting it all together](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture#putting-it-all-together)

It seems it did not fire for "_framePool.FrameArrived"

Comment: I have tested with above code and it could capture [outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD51W.png) app. I could not reproduce your issue, Please check if you have miss some key procedure .

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT What is your project target windows version and your current os version? My project is v 1809 and os is 1809

Comment: The app's target version is 1903 min version is 1809 and the system version 1909.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT As the doc, it indicates that its mini version is 1803. Could you make a test with v 1809?

Comment: I just tested with 1809 (min and target version) and it works well, could you test with the high system version?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Due to the company policy, I could not upgrade the system version.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205064/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-edward).

Comment: could you try to use  the screen capturer  to capture uwp mail app?

Comment: I have tested within os version 1809, it also works well, could you test using screen capture to capture uwp mail app?